# Extend calculator with complex and rational module(using dynamic binding)

Tags: oop, go, inheritance, dynamic, polymorphism

I already made calculator that can compute with integers and real numbers(i made it with go).
Then I want to make it possible to calculate complex and rational numbers by adding those modules.
(it can also calculate when types are mixed)
It can be easy if I check types of operands every time(runtime) and take care of each case, but I want to solve it with dynamic binding. Guys can you tell me the idea of how to solve this problem

Comment: Please explain what you mean by “dynamic binding”

Comment: What I intended to do is to make use of object-oriented characteristics by dynamic bi-ding without writing a logic to ask each type at runtime. Sorry i’m not good at describing something

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think by dynamic typing, you're probably referring to how in eg  C++ and Java, dynamic binding is essentially having reference to a base class that can point to a derived class (because the derived class "*is a*" base class).

One might say that the base class defines the *interface* behind which derived classes morph.  If the derived classes replace methods of the base class, a reference to the base class can still access those methods in the derived class.

Base class can define some methods to provide some "base" functionality to its derived classes.  If those classes don't redefine the method, the base class's method can be called.

In go, both these concepts exist, but they're quite different.

Go has an explicit `interface` keyword that defines method signatures but no methods.  Any value *implicitly* satisfies that interface if it has methods of the same name with the same signature.

```
type LivingBeing interface {
    TakeInEnergy()
    ExpelWaste()
}
```

The interface type becomes a valid type in the code.  We can pass an interface to a function, and without knowing the type satisfying that interface, can call its methods:

```
func DoLife(being LivingBeing) {
   being.TakeInEnergy()
   being.ExpelWaste()
}
```

This is valid code, but not complete code.  Unlike with base classes in other languages, *interfaces cannot define functions*, only their signatures.  It is purely and only an interface definition.  **We have to define the types that satisfy the interface separately from the interface itself**.

```
type Organism struct{}

func (o *Organism) TakeInEnergy() {}

func (o *Organism) ExpelWaste() {}
```

We now have a type `organism` that satisfies `LivingBeing`.  It is something like a base class, but if we wanted to build on it, we can't use subclassing because Go doesn't implement it.   But Go does provide something similar  called [embedding types](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go#embedding).

In this example I'll define a new organism, Animal, that draws `ExpelWaste()` from `LivingBeing`, but defines its own `TakeInEnergy()`:

```
type Animal struct {
    Organism  // the syntax for an embedded type: type but no field name
}

func (a *Animal) TakeInEnergy() {
    fmt.Printf("I am an animal")
}
```

What isn't obvious from that code is that because `Animal`'s `Organism` is not a named field, its fields and methods are accessible directly from `Animal`.  It's *almost* as if `Animal` "*is a*n" organism.

However it is *not * an organism.  It is a different type, and it would be more accurate to think of object embedding as syntactic sugar to automatically promote `Organism`'s fields and methods to `Animal`.

Since go is statically and explicitly typed, `DoLife` cannot take an `Organism` and then be passed an `Animal`: it doesn't have the same type:

```
/* This does not work.  Animal embeds organism, but *is not* an organism */
func DoLife(being *Organism) {
   being.TakeInEnergy()
   being.ExpelWaste()
}
func main() {
    var a = &Animal{Organism{}}
    DoLife(&Animal{})
}
```

```
cannot use &Animal{} (type *Animal) as type *Organism in argument to DoLife
```

That's why `interface` exists - so that both `Organism` and `Animal` (and indeed, even `Plant` or `ChemotrophBacteria`)  can be passed *as a* `LivingBeing`.

Putting it all together, here's [the code I've been working from:](https://play.golang.org/p/fZLouNw9bxv)

```
package main

import "fmt"

type LivingBeing interface {
    TakeInEnergy()
    ExpelWaste()
}

type Organism struct{}

func (o *Organism) TakeInEnergy() {
}

func (o *Organism) ExpelWaste() {}

type Animal struct {
    Organism
}

func DoLife(being LivingBeing) {
    being.TakeInEnergy()
    being.ExpelWaste()
}

func (a *Animal) TakeInEnergy() {
    fmt.Printf("I am an animal")
}

func main() {
    var a = &Animal{Organism{}}
    DoLife(a)
}
```

There are a few caveats:

1. Syntactically, If you want to declare an embedded literal you must explicitly provide its type.   In my example `Organism` has no fields so there's nothing to declare, but I still left the explicit type in there to point you in the right direction.
2. `DoLife` can call the right `TakeInEnergy` on a LivingBeing, but `Organism`'s methods *cannot*.  They see only the embedded `Organism`.

```
func (o *Organism) ExpelWaste() {
    o.getWaste() //this will always be Organism's getWaste, never Animal's
}

func (o *Organism)getWaste() {}

func (a *Animal)getWaste() {
    fmt.Println("Animal waste")
}
```

Simlarly if you pass only the embedded part, then it's going to call its own `TakeInEnergy()`, not that of `Animal`; there's no `Animal` left!

```
func main() {
    var a = &Animal{Organism{}}
    DoLife(&a.Organism)
}
```

In summary,

- Define explict `interface` and use that type wherever you want "polymorphic" behavior
- Define base types and embed them in other types to share base functionality.
- Don't expect the "base" type to ever "bind" to functions from the "derived" type.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I already wrote it with using interface.(number interface and implement it with integer, float struct etc. Can you tell me how to make use of object-oriented characteristics(especially dynamic binding) when performing operations that are mixed with multiple types(ex 1/2 + 1.34)?